# getting empty response angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9

I have created a login module using angular 9. When i try to login with right credentials i got the 200 response with json i checked it in inspect element. But when i debug the angular service the response is empty. please someone help me out why this is happening?

**login.service.ts**

```
   load(userLogin : UserLogin): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       this._http
        .post('login',userLogin)
        .pipe(
          catchError(res => {
            resolve();
            return throwError(res);
          })
        )
        .subscribe(
         (res: any) => {
            console.log('result', res);
          },
          () => {
            reject();
          },
          () => {
            resolve();
          }
        );
    });
  }
```

**LoginResource.java**

```
  @PostMapping
  public Map<String, Object> login(@RequestBody @Validated LoginDto loginDto) throws IOException {
    log.info("=>Login POST");
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authReq =
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginDto.getEmail(), loginDto.getPassword());
    Authentication auth = authenticationManager.authenticate(authReq);
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
    String jwt = jwtUtils.generateJwtToken(auth);
    Registration userDetails = (Registration) auth.getPrincipal();

    List<String> roles =
        userDetails.getRoles().stream()
            .map(Role::getPrivileges)
            .flatMap(Collection::stream)
            .map(Privilege::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return new HashMap<String, Object>() {
          {
            put("token", jwt);
            put("id", userDetails.getId());
            put("username", userDetails.getUserName());
            put("roles", roles);
          }
        };
  }
```

Comment: use only return this._http.post('login',userLogin).toPromise() , and when you call the method use async function with try/catch and await

Comment: You need to say how you monitored the response. I'd also say this is a needless conversion from an observable to a promise. Observables offer more features and would serve you well to spend some time to learn it.